# Counting the words in a string for cat

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to count up the number of times the word or string "cat" appears in a given variable string p.  However, my code is not correct, although I think my logic is.  I need the output to print out 'Number of cat occurs: 2' only once. Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

```
p = 'thecatisnapingandtheothercatiseating'
count = 0
word = 'cat'
for i in range(0, len(p)+1):
    if p[i:i+3] == word:
        count += 1
        print('Number of times cat occurs: ' + str(count))
```

Comment: ask yourself "what is `s`?" and you will see the issue

Comment: I fixed the typo, but I am still getting an error

Comment: You didn't mention an error in the original question. What error are you getting?

Comment: I need it to show the TOTAL of the number of the string 'cat'.  The output is keep is showing Number of times cat occurs: 1, Number of times cat occurs: 2.  I only need to show or display it once as Number of cat occurs: 2

Comment: move your print statement after your for loop

Comment: just for reference, getting a result that you don't expect is not an _error message_

Comment: In case someone ever needs to do this in non-assignment code: `p.count('cat')`

Comment: BTW you can simplify the print like this: `print('Number of times cat occurs:', count)`

Comment: `for i in range(0, len(p)-2):` since in the line below you are going from doing `p[i:i+3]`

Comment: @pythonic833 what do you mean by len(p)-2?  I don't understand the meaning of this at all.  Why are we subtracting 2 elements from the length of the string variable p?  How is this related the string splicing code, p[i:1+3]?  Can you elaborate on this to help me understand the concept?

Comment: Cat has 3 letters, therefore you only need to iterate up to the third last letter (which is at the last position in `range(0, len(p)-2)`

Comment: @pythonic833 can you give me an example and break it down in laymens term?  I am new to CS and coding :/

Answer (score 2):

You just have to move the print to outside of the for loop:

```
p = 'thecatisnapingandtheothercatiseating'
count = 0
word = 'cat'
for i in range(0, len(p)+1):
    if p[i:i+3] == word:
        count += 1


print('Number of times cat occurs: ' + str(count))
>>>Number of times cat occurs: 2
```

Look @Tim, complementing and extending @pythonic833 answer, your for loop statement should be `for i in range(0, len(p)-2):`, to do that `i=0,1,2,...,len(p)-3`,
because for example, taking `p = 'thecatisnap', len(p)=11`, you are going to compare strings like this:

```
'the'=='cat', 'hec'=='cat', 'eca'=='cat', ... , p[i:i+3] == 'cat'
```

So as @pythonic833 said, you only need to iterate up to the third last letter, 
because after there, you will be comparing words with less than three letters:

```
#iterarion 
i=len(p)-3=8
p[i:i+3]='nap'

Compare 'nap'=='cat'

#iterarion 
i=len(p)-2=9
p[i:i+3]='ap'

Compare 'ap'=='cat'

#iterarion
i=len(p)-1=10
p[i:i+3]='p'

Compare 'p'=='cat'

#iteration 
i=len(p)=11
p[i:i+3]=''
Compare ''=='cat'
```

So after the iteration when `i=len(p)-2`, it doesn't make sense that you continue comparing.

Comment: thank you so much for clearing that up and explaining it to me!

Comment: Glad it helps you @Tim. I'll appreciate your upvote! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `re.findall`:

```
import re

p = 'thecatisnapingandtheothercatiseating'
word = 'cat'
print(f'Number of times cat occurs: {len(re.findall(word, p))}')
```

Prints

```
Number of times cat occurs: 2
```

Or maybe more readable version:

```
import re

p = 'thecatisnapingandtheothercatiseating'
word = 'cat'
count = len(re.findall(word, p))
print(f'Number of times cat occurs: {count}')
```

---

Your own code is also fine, it would work with a bit modification:

```
p = 'thecatisnapingandtheothercatiseatingcat'
count = 0
word = 'cat'
for i in range(-~len(p) - len(word)):
    if p[i:i + len(word)] == word:
        count += 1
print(f'Number of times cat occurs: {count}')
```

Or:

```
p = 'thecatisnapingandtheothercatiseatingcat'
count = 0
word = 'cat'
for i in range(len(p) + 1 - len(word)):
    if p[i:i + len(word)] == word:
        count += 1
print(f'Number of times cat occurs: {count}')
```

`-~len(p)` is a bitwise operation for incrementing. `-~i` simply means `i + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

There's always the `count` method to use:

```
p = 'thecatisnapingandtheothercatiseating'
word = 'cat'
print(f'Number of times cat occurs: {p.count(word)}')
```

Output:

```
Number of times cat occurs: 2
```